# Change bar chart column structure

Tags: matlab

I change the column color in the bar chart but the problem that when i print the paper in black and white all columns look the same, so I am wondering if there is any way to change the column shape from inside (like cross or circles) so i can differentiate between columns in black and white ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try, amongst others,  this matlab exchange entry called [Hatch fill patterns plus Color & Invert](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24021-hatch-fill-patterns-plus-color-invert).

[image]